# How to repair 'update-ref' error in git

Tags: git

I have a repository with a branch 'current-production'. I was playing with 'update-ref' to try and set 'current-production' to a new commit, and I ended up aliasing (?) 'current-production' to the commit hash.

I deleted the original branch, and now if I do:

git checkout current-production

I get a commit snapshot in detached head mode.

My question is:

A) What is 'current-production'? It's not a branch or tag and 'git show-ref current-production' produces no result.

B) How can I delete it?

SOLUTION

I'm not sure which 'update-ref' command caused this, but I found I eventually did a 'find' from .git itself and found a file with a commit hash named 'current-production' right in the .git directory. Deleted that file and everything fine.

Comment: Take a look in the `.git/refs` folder.

Comment: Nothing from 'find .git/refs/ -name "*current-production*"' or manual search. I see no reference to 'current-production'.

Comment: Might also check `packed-refs`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what state you're in without knowing exactly what you did to get there.

Try running `grep -r current-production .git`, and see what you find.

You could also try `git reflog show` and see if the log helps you backtrack. (If you see a healthy state in the log, you can also revert to it).

Instead of `update-ref`, if you want to update your branch to a different commit, simply check it out, then run `git reset --hard new_commit` (you can give a commit sha, or branch name, or other valid form), followed by `push` or `push -f`.